# Conditional expectation of exponential Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $f\in L^2[0,T]$. Show that conditional expectation 
$$
\mathbb{E}\bigg[ e^{\int_{0}^T f(s)dB_s}\bigg| \mathscr{F}_t\bigg]
  =\exp \left(\int_0^t f(s)\ dB_s
            + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^T |f(s)|^2\ ds \right)
$$

Where $(\mathscr{F}_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ denotes the filtration generated by $(B_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$

I tried to follow the answer given in [Expectation of Exponential of Stochastic Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013714/expectation-of-exponential-of-stochastic-integral)
but couldn't get the answer.

Comment: In this case $B_s$ is what?

Comment: $B_s$ is Brownian motion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $B$ is a Brownian motion and $f \in L_2[0,T]$.

**First method:**

We know that $\forall t \in [0,T]$, $\int_0^t f(s)dB_s$ is a Wiener integral. Therefore, we can use the fact that $T\geq s \geq t$, $\int_t^s f(u)dB_u$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_t$ **(1)** and follows a centered Gaussian distribution with variance $\int_s^t |f(u)|^2du$ **(2)**.
Thus,
\begin{align}
E\left[\exp\left(\int_0^Tf(s)dB_s\right)|\mathcal{F}_t\right] &=E\left[\exp\left(\int_t^Tf(s)dB_s\right)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]\exp\left(\int_0^tf(s)dB_s\right) \\
&=E\left[\exp\left(\int_t^Tf(s)dB_s\right)\right]\exp\left(\int_0^tf(s)dB_s\right) \\
&=\exp\left(\int_0^tf(s)dB_s+\frac12\int_t^T|f(s)|^2ds\right)
\end{align}
In the last equality, I used the following known result : $N\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2), E[\exp(cN)] = \exp(c\mu +\frac12c^2\sigma^2)$.

Remarks:

- It seems that there is an issue in the writing of the problem. It should be $\int_\color{red}t^\color{red}T |f(s)|^2ds$.
- You can show with ease the property **(1)** and **(2)** by first assuming that $f$ is a step function and then use a density argument.

**Second method:**

Denoting $Y_t = \int_0^t f(s)dB_s - \frac12 \int_0^t |f(s)|^2ds$, we can apply Ito lemma to the function $\phi(x) = \exp(x)$ using $Y_t$. We have that
\begin{align}
d\exp(Y_t) &= \exp(Y_t)(dY_t + \frac12 d\langle Y_t \rangle ) \\
&= \exp(Y_t)(f(t)dB_t - \frac12f(t)^2dt + \frac12f(t)^2dt) \\
&=\exp(Y_t)f(t)dB_t \\
\end{align}
We know that the RHS is a squared martingale. Therefore, the process $\lbrace{\exp(Y_t)\rbrace}_{0\leq t \leq T}$ is a martingale. For more  details, look at this wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dol%C3%A9ans-Dade_exponential).

Comment: Very helpful answer. The textbook (An elementary introduction to stochastic interest rate models, 2nd edition, Nicolas Privault, Exercise 1.6) give the integral from 0 to T but I think it is not correct after seeing your answer.